# How can I detect which Android native function that is hooked by Mobile Substrate: MSHookFunction?

Tags: android, function-hooking, frida

I want to detect hook behavior of MSHookFunction on Android. This is Mobile Substrate I use in my test app https://github.com/Breathleas/Android-Hooking-Template-Cydia-Substrate/tree/master/jni/Substrate

After complete function hook. I tried comparing the `.text` section between the in-memory module and the shared object lib file but couldn't find the trampoline function. Here is the Frida script on the codeshare that I referenced https://codeshare.frida.re/@lichao890427/find-android-hook/. The origin function is hooked but `.text` section data in memory is same with shared object lib file. I also used memory tools like Cheat Engine or Game-Guardian (on Android) to look for the offset I hooked in memory and found it wasn't replaced. So, how did MSHookFunction work and how can I detect hooked functions ?